# Showing integer instead of decimal when whole number is used in a ToString("0.0") in a razor form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, tostring

I'm displaying a decimal number like this on my page

```
>@Model.Rating.ToString("0.0") // ex. 4.8, 3.9, 1.2, etc
```

This works fine when the rating is a decimal like 3.7 or 4.1
but if the number is whole, like 3, it displays a 3.0.

Is there any easy way to show just the 3, not the 3.0 without 
using a conditional statement (ex. if) to check?

Comment: Use `.ToString("0.#")` instead.  [Demo here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fyq7Ls)

Comment: Try `ToString("#,#0.0")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use something like `@Model.Rating.ToString("0.#");`

The `#` in the string format indicates that the value is optional.

See this [Custom numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the--custom-specifier) page on Microsoft Docs for more information.

Hope this helps!